# Telegram Bot API: obtain all groups my bot is a member of

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm looking for a way to see all chats/channels/groups my bot participating in except to use webhook or `getUpdates` method. These methods are not suitable for me because to use them you need to send a message to chat or do something like that and you have to repeat this procedure for every chat. Is there any way to get a list of all the groups at once not making any changes to them except adding the bot itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately currently its not possible.